# Should I create both www and non-www site aliases?

Tags: dotnetnuke

Should I create both www and non-www site aliases for my portals, i.e. www.mydomain.com *and* mydomain.com?

I currently have both with the www alias defined as the primary and everything works, but I'm wondering what the recommended practice is?

**Edit**: This is specifically a DotNetNuke configuration question. I understand the difference between the 2 aliases but want to understand whether it is worth using both specifically from a DotNetNuke perspective.

Comment: You may want to see [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11560/seo-preference-for-www-or-http-protocol-redirection-do-www-websites-rank-bet)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do both, with a rewrite rule to forward to the one you want to be the canonical one (so you don't miss any statistics).

Comment: As of DNN 6 there's no longer a need for URL rewriting to achieve this. It now supports mapping between site aliases.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no need to do both. I enter whichever one I want to be the primary (usually with the www.). This has worked fine for at least the last 5 years in at least 50 DNN sites I've created and hosted.